# Why is Wolfram Alpha miscomputing this problem?

Tags: factorial, wolfram-alpha

I was incorporating Wolfram Alpha into an API I am build, and to test it entered a few equations. One of the equations I entered was as follows.

```
!6/(!3*!3)
```

This obviously equals 20, but my API spat back 66.25!

At first I thought I had mis-coded my API, but then I tried it on WA and got the same result.

Why is WA making this mistake?

Comment: If you're meaning to write a factorial, then that's what's wrong; you're not writing one.  $6!/(3!*3!)$ evaluatees to $20$ in Wolfram Alpha, $!n$ is the subfactorial function (wolfram even says so)

Comment: As far as I know the ! of a factorial - if that is what you want - is to be put on the right and not on the left

Comment: I voted to leave open. The answer to the question seems to be, "You're confusing two functions, $n!$ and $!n$, that are not the same." How is a question off-topic, if that's the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you tagged this with factorial I assume what you meant to write was:

```
6!/(3!*3!)
```

You put the ! on the wrong side. n! is n factorial. !n is sub factorial.

Next time just type in the words to make sure you have the right syntax(e.g., factorial(6)((factorial(6)*factorial(6)))

Comment: So what is this sub-factorial?

Comment: To quote Wolfram Alpha (haha)The sub factorial of n is the number of permutations of n objects in which no object appears in its natural place. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Subfactorial.html

Comment: Ok. Thanks man.

Answer (score 4):

The issue lay in the fact that the notation $!6$ means something very specific to Wolfram Alpha. You likely want it to mean $6$ factorial (i.e. $6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$). However Wolfram Alpha interprets $!6$ to be the subfactorial of $6$ which is the number of permutations of $6$ elements which leaves *no element* fixed. In this case, $!6 = 265$ and $!3 = 2$, giving $\frac{!6}{!3\cdot !3} = \frac{265}{2\cdot 2} = 66.25$ as you obtained. Just put your $!$ on the correct side and you'll be fine. The difference between $n!$ and $!n$ is that $n!$ counts the *total* number of permutations of $n$ objects, including those that *do* leave some elements fixed so in general $!n \le n!$.

Answer (score 0):

Alpha uses the $!x$ notation for

$$\frac{\Gamma(x+1,-1)}{e},$$ where $$\Gamma(x,a)=\int_x^{\infty}t^{-a}e^tdt,$$
the incomplete Gamma function.